# enum() always enter a lower number

Tags: laravel

I am creating a table that has an enum type of various options that are registered in the model.

**MIGRATION**

```
Schema::create('timelines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('timelineable_id');
            $table->string('timelineable_type');
            $table->enum('type', [Timeline::SURVEY, Timeline::COMMENT, Timeline::SHAREPOST, Timeline::FOLLOW, Timeline::SHARESOCIAL]);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**MODEL TIMELINE**

```
class Timeline extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    const SURVEY = 1;
    const COMMENT = 2;
    const SHAREPOST = 3;
    const FOLLOW = 4;
    const SHARESOCIAL = 5;


    public function timelineable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

The problem comes when I insert a record in the table, it creates everything fine except the "type" value which always adds the value Timeline::xxx -1 .

```
$commentCreate->timelines()->create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'type' => Timeline::COMMENT,
        ]);
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Because you have set the enum type array and it starts from 0 so the index number of Timeline::COMMENT is 1 so that's why you are getting the value `Timeline::xxx -1`

Comment: But shouldn't it take the value set in the Timeline model constants, instead of the order in which they were created in the migration? This confuses me ... So why do you have to set the values in the constants if it takes them in the order of the matrix?

Comment: If this is MySQL I would imagine it has to do with what [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) says *If you retrieve an ENUM value in a numeric context, the column value's index is returned.*. In your case the enum is numeric values so it *may* always be in a numeric context. Just speculating though

Comment: It may also be the fact that that *If you store a number into an ENUM column, the number is treated as the index into the possible values, and the value stored is the enumeration member with that index.* (again from [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
The value of //$EnumValue = 2

```
$value = "COMMENT";
$Enumvalue = Timeline ::enum($value);

$commentCreate->timelines()->create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'type' => $Enumvalue,
        ]);

class Timeline extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    const SURVEY = 1;
    const COMMENT = 2;
    const SHAREPOST = 3;
    const FOLLOW = 4;
    const SHARESOCIAL = 5;

    public function enum($string){
        return constant('Timeline ::'.$string);
    }
}
```